# Is there any way to prevent Hero transition on specific routes?

Tags: flutter

we give same tags to Hero widgets and watch their transition between route transitions. I want to prevent specific Hero tag between specific routes. Is there any solution for this? Can I say don't animate between this specific routes like this?

Example:

```
HeroControllerScope(
  controller: HeroController(
    excludedRoutes: [Routes.BOOKING_SUMMARY, Routes.SUPER_PRODUCTS],
  ),
  //lorem ipsum image
  child: Hero(
    child: Image.network('https://i.picsum.photos/id/184/200/300.jpg'),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use class [HeroMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HeroMode-class.html)

```
HeroMode(
      enabled: Get.currentRoute != Routes.BOOKING_SUMMARY && Get.currentRoute != Routes.SUPER_PRODUCTS,
      child: Hero(
    child: Image.network('https://i.picsum.photos/id/184/200/300.jpg'),
  ),
)
```